# How to get rid of this bad shading?

Tags: modeling, mesh, shaders, edit-mode, topology

I'm trying to do a hard surface mesh (Not sure if it's considered a hard surface) and I'm getting this bad shading.

I've applied ***WeightedNormal*** modifier and it didn't help. It's good to mention that everything is kept in quads.
Normals are recalculated and there are no ***Custom Split Normals Data*** on the mesh. Also, there are no **Doubles** on the mesh.

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]
What causes this bad shading? Is it related to the topology? And how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: I'm confused, this looks like I would expect it

Comment: Maybe add a Subdivision Surface modifier (but you'll need to bevel some edges)?

Comment: @Frederik Steinmetz I've marked the part with bad shading, check out the screenshots again.

Comment: Have you tried Shade smooth?

Comment: @moonboots I've added a subdivision modifier and that solved the issue. But it increased the polycount significantly. Is there another way to maintain the current polycount but at the same time keep a good shading? Thank you.

Comment: @Bentley Carpenter Yes, I've enabled the Auto Smooth.

Comment: It doesn't look like you can avoid subdivision (a level of 1 seems enough) but I may be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are artifacts that stem from faces that are far from sqare. Long faces can cause problems. The quick and clean fix is to insert what's called a relaxing loop cut. Add them with the loop cut tool or CTRL + R.

[image]

Before you go crazy with the loop cuts, though, check the model with the render engine of your choice, Cycles is often able to correct them without any tweaking on your part.

Comment: Your answer solved my problem. Thank you for your time and effort to answer my question. I appreciate your help.